# How do you list the permissions for all installed Android Apps from another App

Tags: android, android-manifest

Im developing an anti-malware type application.
for that my application needs to know permissions given to other applications installed on the phone...
I've seen this thing in few other applications like LookOut....
How it is done...

Also Pls do you have any other solutions or suggestions on this application...
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PackageManager:

```
                      PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                      PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                      PermissionInfo[] pi = packageInfo.permissions;
```